# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript not injecting script only on one page

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is in the `Page_Load` method, and I've verified through debugging that the code is running.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                GetType(),
                "help meeeeee",
                "writeName('" + Session["firstname"] + " " + Session["lastname"] + "');" +
                "fillTable(" + GetSalesOrder(1) + ");",
                true);
```

I've also verified that the method `GetSalesOrder` is also running when this code is executed. The strange thing is that on another page in the same project, this exact same method works completely fine.

Comment: Are you returning the above code to Ajax call?

Comment: Check also that there is no script error somewhere else in the same page. This could prevent further scripts from executing.

Comment: @Win Nope just regular js functions

Comment: @Marcel The console is reporting no errors.